# Unable to install Veracode Scan plugin in Jenkins 2.249.3 version

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, veracode

Unable to install Veracode Scan plugin in Jenkins 2.249.3 version

```
    Failure -
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:465)
at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:503)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:990)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:948)
at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:105)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:286)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:735)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:678)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1593)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1498)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getHeaderField(HttpURLConnection.java:3061)
at java.net.URLConnection.getHeaderFieldLong(URLConnection.java:629)
at java.net.URLConnection.getContentLengthLong(URLConnection.java:501)
at java.net.URLConnection.getContentLength(URLConnection.java:485)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getContentLength(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:412)
at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$UpdateCenterConfiguration.download(UpdateCenter.java:1264)
```

Caused: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1950)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1945)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getChainedException(HttpURLConnection.java:1944)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1514)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1498)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:268)
at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$UpdateCenterConfiguration.download(UpdateCenter.java:1280)
Caused: java.io.IOException: Failed to load https://updates.jenkins.io/download/plugins/veracode-scan/20.9.11.0/veracode-scan.hpi to C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Jenkins.jenkins\plugins\veracode-scan.jpi.tmp
at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$UpdateCenterConfiguration.download(UpdateCenter.java:1287)
Caused: java.io.IOException: Failed to download from https://updates.jenkins.io/download/plugins/veracode-scan/20.9.11.0/veracode-scan.hpi (redirected to: https://get.jenkins.io/plugins/veracode-scan/20.9.11.0/veracode-scan.hpi)
at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$UpdateCenterConfiguration.download(UpdateCenter.java:1321)
at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$DownloadJob._run(UpdateCenter.java:1869)
at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$InstallationJob._run(UpdateCenter.java:2147)
at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$DownloadJob.run(UpdateCenter.java:1843)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at hudson.remoting.AtmostOneThreadExecutor$Worker.run(AtmostOneThreadExecutor.java:118)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that you are trying to download the plugin through the update center. You can also try to directly download the **hpi** file through https://updates.jenkins.io/download/plugins/veracode-scan/ and [install it](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/plugins/):

A logged-in Jenkins administrator may upload the file from within the web UI:

1. Navigate to the Manage Jenkins > Manage Plugins page in the web UI.
2. Click on the Advanced tab.
3. Choose the .hpi file under the Upload Plugin section.
4. Upload the plugin file.
5. Restart Jenkins master in order the changes to take effect.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I was unable to download the hpi file from the URL since Friday. Now I am able to download theplugin directly from Jenkins Available section.